# win32: improve performance of disk write

Tags: performance, winapi, disk

In order to write to HD at max. performance I'm using overlapped I/O.
It works.

Upon acquiring 4MB of data (from sensor) I'm writing it to disk.
Then, upon getting the next 4MB I first ask if the previous writing completed.

How can I know what is the optimal block size (4MB ?) that is best for my disk ?

```
// AsyncFile.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AsyncFile.h"

/****************************************************************************/
CAsyncFile::CAsyncFile()
{

}

/****************************************************************************/
CAsyncFile::~CAsyncFile()
{

}

/****************************************************************************/
int CAsyncFile::OpenFile(char *pcFileName,
    bool        bAsync,     // Whether async read/write is required
    bool        bWrite)     // True is file is used for writing to
{
    DWORD   dwAsyncMask = bAsync ? (FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING) : 0;
    DWORD   dwCreation = bWrite ? CREATE_ALWAYS : OPEN_EXISTING;
    DWORD   dwAccess = bWrite ? GENERIC_WRITE : GENERIC_READ;
    DWORD   dwShareMode = bWrite ? FILE_SHARE_READ : FILE_SHARE_WRITE;

    if (strlen(pcFileName) < sizeof(m_cFileName))
        strcpy_s(m_cFileName, 256, pcFileName);
    else
        m_cFileName[0] = 0; // NULL (error - file name is too long)

                            // Calling openFile() sets a valid value to the file handle
    m_hFileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    // Auto reset (manual reset=false), init state = false, no name
    m_hIoCompleted = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);


    // Init OVERLAPPED structure, for async read
    m_tOverlapped.Offset = 0;
    m_tOverlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
    m_tOverlapped.hEvent = m_hIoCompleted;
    m_Event = m_tOverlapped.hEvent;

    if (m_hFileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // File is already opened; check open mode
        if ((bAsync == m_bAsync) && (bWrite == m_bWrite))
            return (ASYNCFILE_OK);

        // File is already opened, but in other mode; Should close file
        // before using it again
        return ASYNCFILE_FILE_IS_NOT_IN_WRITE_MODE;
    }


    m_hFileHandle =
        CreateFile((LPCTSTR)m_cFileName,
            dwAccess,                       // Open for read or write
            dwShareMode,                    // 
            NULL,                           // No SECURITY_ATTRBUTES
            dwCreation,                     // Open exisiting file (if read) \ create new (if write)
            dwAsyncMask,                    // For asynchronous operations, for maximum asynchronous performence
            0);

    if (m_hFileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        return ASYNCFILE_FAILED_TO_OPEN_FILE;
    }

    //In case file opened for reading, get its size
    if (bWrite == false)
    {
        GetFileSizeEx(m_hFileHandle, &m_FileSize);
    }

    // Save open mode
    m_bAsync = bAsync;
    m_bWrite = bWrite;

    return ASYNCFILE_OK;
}

/****************************************************************************/
int CAsyncFile::CloseFile()
{
    //BOOL Status;

    if (!CloseHandle(m_hFileHandle))
        return ASYNCFILE_FAILED_TO_CLOSE_FILE;

    if (!CloseHandle(m_hIoCompleted))
        return ASYNCFILE_FAILED_TO_CLOSE_FILE;

    return ASYNCFILE_OK;
}

/****************************************************************************/
int CAsyncFile::StartAsyncRead(void*        pBuffer,
    DWORD       dwReadSize,
    bool*       pbEof)
{
    *pbEof = false; // By default, EOF is false
    int iError;

    if (m_hFileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (false);

    if (!ReadFile(m_hFileHandle,
        pBuffer,
        dwReadSize,
        NULL,           // actual bytes read is not valid now
        &m_tOverlapped))
    {

        if ((iError = GetLastError()) == ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
        {
            *pbEof = true;
            return ASYNCFILE_OK;
        }
        else if (!(m_bAsync && (iError == ERROR_IO_PENDING)))
        {
            return ASYNCFILE_START_READ_FAILED;
        }
    }

    return ASYNCFILE_OK;
}


/****************************************************************************/
int CAsyncFile::WaitAsyncOperationEnd(DWORD*    pdwActualBytesTransferred)
{
    if (m_hFileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return ASYNCFILE_WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION_FAILED;


    // Wait for read operation to complete
    if (!GetOverlappedResult(m_hFileHandle,
        &m_tOverlapped,
        pdwActualBytesTransferred,
        true))
        return ASYNCFILE_WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION_FAILED;

    return ASYNCFILE_OK;
}

/****************************************************************************/
int CAsyncFile::StartAsyncWrite(void*       pSrcBuf,
    DWORD       dwSize)     // In bytes
{
    int iError;

    if (!WriteFile(m_hFileHandle,
        pSrcBuf,
        dwSize,
        NULL,           // actual bytes written is not valid now
        &m_tOverlapped))
    {
        iError = GetLastError();

        if (iError != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            return ASYNCFILE_START_WRITE_FAILED;
    }

    return ASYNCFILE_OK;
}

/****************************************************************************/
void CAsyncFile::SetFilePosition(UINT64 Position)
{
    m_tOverlapped.Offset = Position & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    m_tOverlapped.OffsetHigh = Position >> 32;
}

/****************************************************************************/
UINT64 CAsyncFile::GetFilePosition()
{
    UINT64 Position;

    Position = (m_tOverlapped.Offset) | ((UINT64)m_tOverlapped.OffsetHigh << 32);

    return (Position);
}

/****************************************************************************/
UINT64 CAsyncFile::GetFileSize()
{
    return (m_FileSize.QuadPart);
}
```

Comment: This is certainly dependent of the OS storage device stack settings (eg queue depth), the driver and the actual HDD (latency, throughput, IOPS) and even possibly the RAM (because buffers are often copied many times). It is certainly far from being simple to estimate and easier to test in practice.

Comment: Performance optimization starts with profiling. You will have to measure your current performance first. Once that is done, compare the value to the theoretical maximum. Without those values there's no basis to go off of.

Comment: You may want to check the optimal transfer length / granularity for the drive you're writing to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-device_copy_offload_descriptor

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the average size of your files as well. If your file sizes are constantly ranging near 7 to 8 MB, then there would be some benefit in increasing the buffer size to 8192KB. How old is the drive? How often have you used it, many other factors come into play. We are able to learn more about this topic from an excellent piece of software called [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The total file size can reach to 1TB.